# Remove duplicate rows as an additional column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table for student records and I have some duplicate rows for the student dimension cause of the major, so now I have something like this:

```
ID Major
----------
 1  CS
 1  Mgt
```

What I want is to combine this two rows in this form:

```
ID Major Major2
----------
 1   CS   Mgt
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a number for pivoting.  Then you can pivot using either `pivot` or conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then major end) as major_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then major end) as major_2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Note:  you should validate that "2" is large enough to count the majors.  You can get the maximum using:

```
select top 1 id, count(*)
from t
group by id
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `(select null)` in `partition by id order by` part?

Comment: OK, I've found that this effectively means "whatever order". Sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 0):

If you have at most two different values of major:

```
select  a.id as id, 
        a.major as major, 
        b.major as major2
from    YOUR_TABLE a
left join YOUR_TABLE b on
a.id = b.id
and (b.major is null or a.major > b.major)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will help you**

```
Select 
ID,
(select top 1 Major from <Your_Table> where id=T.Id order by Major) Major,
(case when count(Id)>1 then (select top 1 Major from #temp where id=T.Id order by Major desc) else null end) Major2
from <Your_Table> T
Group By
ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot function directly

```
SELECT  [ID],[CS] AS Major , [Mgt] AS Major2 from Your_Table_Name
PIVOT
(max(Major)for [Major] IN ([CS] , [Mgt]))as p
```